# How to find and move where Docker is storing its data?

Tags: centos, docker

I'm running a program on a server through a web browser trying to get it to run.  I attempt to install an add-on to this program, but I get an error:

Error: Operation failed
Application not installed: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

which is bizarre because the disk that I'm running this on has 1.4 terabytes available.

How can I find out the directory that Docker is working out of, and change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default on direct installs on Linux (so not Docker Desktop, and not a Snap), docker uses `/var/lib/docker` for storing images, containers, and volumes. The command `docker system df` will show you disk usage, and `docker system prune` can be used to remove unused containers and images.

To relocate this to another partition, I'd recommend a symlink rather than reconfiguring docker itself, since lots of other tools make the assumption that it will be installed in `/var/lib/docker`. See [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3127) for details but the basic steps should be (as root, and to use `/home/var-docker` as your new location):

```
target=/home/var-docker
systemctl stop docker
mv /var/lib/docker $target
ln -s $target /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```